# Nested NSDictionary with valueForKeyPath returns brackets instead of NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, couchdb, nsdictionary

Source is JSON in CouchDB (relevant data):

```
{
"_id":"f994892f3fb525d73b3b6b8a59000e1d",
"_rev":"3-c431ee9334e9be038d9c935efcf2f049",
"teiXML":[
  {
     "teiHeader":[
        {
           "fileDesc":[
              {
                 "publicationStmt":[
                    {
                       "publisher":"University",
                       "pubPlace":"Someplace",
                       "idno type=\"callNo\"":"ABC 007",
                       "date":"2007"
                    }
                 ],
```

This is the NSDictionary (simplified):

```
<CCouchDBDocument: 0x5842c0> (id:f994892f3fb525d73b3b6b8a59000e1d rev:4-3fc1a36de622529cd67416c9e5ae88da {
"_id" = f994892f3fb525d73b3b6b8a59000e1d;
"_rev" = "4-3fc1a36de622529cd67416c9e5ae88da";
teiXML =     (
            {
        teiHeader =             (
                            {
                fileDesc =                     (
                                            {
                        publicationStmt =                             (
                                                            {
                                date = 2007;
                                "idno type=\"callNo\"" = "ABC 007";
                                publisher = "University";
```

I'd like to get the value of "publisher", so I tried using valueForKeyPath:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[doc valueForKeyPath:@"content.teiXML.teiHeader.fileDesc.publicationStmt.publisher"]);
```

But instead of the value "University" I get this as output:

```
1> 2011-05-26 10:10:02.717 MyApp[12770:707] (
        (
                (
                        (
                "University"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Which is quite annoying. I can get the value with an indexAtObject-combination:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[[doc valueForKeyPath:@"content.teiXML.teiHeader.fileDesc.publicationStmt.publisher"] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Something must be wrong there? There are more values to extract and I don't want to count how many objectAtIndex-repetitions I need to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mentioning the "xml" tag, so I suppose that your `NSDictionary` is being built from some XML data. In this case, one hypothesis that could explain this behavior is that your XML contains repeated keys, like in:

```
<values>
  <value>
  ......
  </value>
  <value>
  ......
  </value>
  ...
</values>
```

Indeed, repeated values like in the examples are not suitable to be treated through Key-Value Coding and are handled internally as `NSArray`s. Now, the actual details of why you get so many nested arrays in your reply are difficult for me to figure out, but this could give you a hint at what is happening.

If this hypothesis does not apply to your case, please share the way you build your NSDictionary.

EDIT: after looking at your JSON, there is something that looks not obvious to me. Look at this:

```
"publicationStmt":[
                {
                   "publisher":"University",
                   "pubPlace":"Someplace",
                   "idno type=\"callNo\"":"ABC 007",
                   "date":"2007"
                }
             ],
```

what I understand is you have nested arrays: plublicationStmt contains an array ([) which at turns contain another (keyed) array ({)...

Is this possibly that produce your result?

Comment: Sorry, I converted the XML to JSON for CouchDB, so the NSDictionary is built from a JSON source, not XML. I'll add the JSON source to the question.

Comment: As expected, the output is an NSArray:
`(gdb) po items
<__NSArrayI 0x53fcf0>(
<__NSArrayI 0x54d4c0>(
<__NSArrayI 0x55dc10>(
<__NSArrayI 0x554280>(
University
)
)
)
)`. I really wonder why?

Comment: Thanks Sergio. However, if I remove the braces {} the JSON is not valid any more. Is there another way to nest the attributes? And why would it return an array if I specify the path correctly to the value?

Comment: Ok, I just looked up an example JSON dataset. I have to remove the brackets [], as there are not so many arrays stored in the file. Hope that solves the problem. Thanks!